# Hirerarchy of holders for the hirerarchy of classes

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns, hierarchy

Given I have a hirerarchy of classes (e.g. android widgets classes) like this:
[image]

I need to create a hirerarchy of holders for this hierarchy of classes, so that every holder can create instance of its class AND somehow apply properties to this instance and also to children holders' instances.

My current structure allows for only two layers of the hierarchy:

```
class MyViewBase {
    protected void applyProperties(View view)
        // Apply View's params
    }
}

class MyTextView extends MyViewBase {
    private TextView textView;
    public MyTextView(Context context){
        textView = new TextView();
        // Apply TextView specific params
        applyParams(textView);
    }
}

// I cannot extend MyTextView since I 
// would get both a Button and a TextView instantinated
class MyButton extends MyViewBase { 
    private TextView textView;
    public MyTextView(Context context){
        textView = new TextView();
        // Apply TextView and Button specific params
        applyParams(textView);
    }
}
```

Using static methods like the one below is not an option since I need the Context in some of the cases

```
protected static void applyTextViewProperties(TextView view){
    // Some code here
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code how to actually implement the hierarchy of holders for the hierarchy of classes

Comment: That question isn't specific enough for the format of this site. Please take a moment and read [help/on-topic] and [ask] for tips on how to improve your question in order to attract the information you are looking for.